# Nested form does not validate association model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm using rails 3.2 with active record and sqlserver. I have a problem with nested forms. I have a model registration which has many registration details and each has a person associated.

Here is the model

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "dbo.EV_INSCRIPCIONES"
    set_primary_key "Id"

    belongs_to :category, :foreign_key => 'CategoriaId'
    has_many :registrationDetails, :foreign_key => 'InscripcionEventoId'
    #has_one :group

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :registrationDetails
    validates_associated :registrationDetails

    validates :Refencia, :presence => true

    #validates_presence_of :category_id

    attr_accessible :registrationDetails, :category,  :Eliminada, :FechaInscripcion, :CreationalDate, :Referencia, :PagoRegistrado, :Acreditado, :registrationDetails_attributes

    #after_initialize :init 

    def init
        write_attribute :Eliminada, false
        write_attribute :Acreditado, false
        write_attribute :PagoRegistrado, false
        write_attribute :CreationalDate, DateTime.now
        write_attribute :FechaInscripcion, DateTime.now
        #write_attribute :Referencia, ''
    end

    def category_id
        self.category.id unless category.nil?
    end

    def category_id=(id)
        self.category = Category.find(id)
    end


end

class RegistrationDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "dbo.EV_INSCRIPCION_DETALLE"
    set_primary_key "Id"

    belongs_to :registration, :foreign_key => 'InscripcionEventoId'
    belongs_to :category, :foreign_key => 'CategoriaId'
    belongs_to :person, :foreign_key => 'ParticipanteId', :primary_key => 'JUGADOR_ID'

    attr_accessible :person, :category, :registration, :Eliminada, :person_attributes

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :person
    validates_associated :person

    after_initialize :init 


    def init
        write_attribute :Eliminada, false

    end

end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "dbo.PKR_JUGADOR"
    set_primary_key "JUGADOR_ID"

    has_many :registrationDetails

    validates_presence_of :CDNI, :CNOMBRES, :CAPELLIDO, :CSEXO,:CCIUDADRESIDENCIA, :DFECHANACIMIENTO
    validates :CDNI, :length => { :minimum => 7, :maximum =>8 }
    #validate :validate_birth_date

    before_save :set_ids

    def set_ids 
        if id.nil?
            _id = Person.maximum(:JUGADOR_ID)
            self.JUGADOR_ID = _id +1
            write_attribute :CNROJUGADOR, _id+1         
        end 
    end     

    after_initialize :init
    def init        
        write_attribute :TIPODOCUMENTO_ID, 1 if read_attribute(:TIPODOCUMENTO_ID).nil? 
    end

    def full_name
        self.surname + ", " + self.name
    end

    protected
        def validate_birth_date
            errors.add(:birth_date, 'must be a valid datetime') if ((Date.strptime(birth_date, "%d/%m/%Y") rescue ArgumentError) == ArgumentError)
        end
```

end

My view

index.html.erb

```
<h1><%= t '.title', :name => @event.CNOMBRETORNEO %> </h1>
<%= render 'form_nested' %>
```

_form_nested

```
<%= form_for @registration, :url => {:controller => "registration", :action => "save"}, :html => {:class=> 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
    <legend><%= t '.legend' %></legend> 
    <% if f.object.errors.any?%>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h3 class="text-error"><%= t '.has-errors' %></h3>
    </div>
    <% end %>


    <input type="hidden" id="event_date" name="event_date" value="<%= @event.DDIAACTIVIDAD.strftime('%Y%m%d') %>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="event_id" name="event_id" value="<%= @event.TORNEOPOKER_ID %>" />

    <%= f.fields_for :registrationDetails do |d|  %>
        <%= render 'details_fields' , :f => d %>
    <% end %>

    <% has_error = f.object.errors.has_key? :category %>
    <div class="control-group<%= " error" if has_error %>">
        <%= f.label :category, :class=> 'control-label' %>
        <div class="controls">
            <%= f.hidden_field :category_id %>
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle-name="presenter_category_id" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
            <%@categorias.each do |x| %>
                <button value="<%= x.Id %>" type="button" class="btn" data-age-from="<%= x.FromAge %>" data-age-to="<%= x.ToAge %>"><%= x.Name %></button>
            <%end  %>
            </div>
            <% if has_error  %>         
            <span class="help-inline"><%=f.object.errors[:category].join(", ")%></span>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><%= t '.save' %></button>
    </div>

<%end%>
```

_detatails_fields

```
<%= f.object.errors.inspect %>

<%= f.fields_for :person do |p| %>
    <%= render 'person_fields', :f => p %>
<% end %>
```

_person_fields

```
<%= f.hidden_field :id %>
<% has_error = f.object.errors.has_key? :CDNI %>
<div class="control-group<%= " error" if has_error %>">
    <%= f.label :CDNI, :class=> 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-book"></i></span>
            <%= f.text_field :CDNI, :class => 'input' %>
            <div class="add-on" id="document_loader"><%= image_tag '6-0.gif' %></div>
        </div>
        <% if has_error  %>         
        <span class="help-inline"><%=f.object.errors[:CDNI].join(", ")%></span>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<% has_error = f.object.errors.has_key? :DFECHANACIMIENTO %>
<div class="control-group<%= " error" if has_error %>">
    <%= f.label :DFECHANACIMIENTO, :class=> 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            <%= f.text_field :DFECHANACIMIENTO, :class=>'input' %>
            <span id="person_age" class="add-on"></span>
        </div>
        <% if has_error  %>         
        <span class="help-inline"><%=f.object.errors[:DFECHANACIMIENTO].join(", ")%></span>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<% has_error = f.object.errors.has_key? :CNOMBRES %>
<div class="control-group<%= " error" if has_error %>">
    <%= f.label :CNOMBRES, :class=> 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
            <%= f.text_field :CNOMBRES,:class=>'input' %>
        </div>
        <% if has_error  %>         
        <span class="help-inline"><%=f.object.errors[:CNOMBRES].join(", ")%></span>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
<% has_error = f.object.errors.has_key? :CAPELLIDO %>
<div class="control-group<%= " error" if has_error %>">
    <%= f.label :CAPELLIDO, :class=> 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
            <%= f.text_field :CAPELLIDO,:class=>'input' %>
        </div>
        <% if has_error  %>         
        <span class="help-inline"><%=f.object.errors[:CAPELLIDO].join(", ")%></span>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :CTELEFONO, :class=> 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-certificate"></i></span>
            <%= f.text_field :CTELEFONO,:class=>'input' %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<% has_error = f.object.errors.has_key? :CSEXO %>
<div class="control-group<%= " error" if has_error %>">
    <%= f.label :CSEXO, :class=> 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
        <%= f.hidden_field :CSEXO %>
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle-name="presenter_sex" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
            <button type="button" class="btn" value="M"><%= t '.masculine' %></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" value="F"><%= t '.femenine' %></button>
        </div>
        <% if has_error  %>         
        <span class="help-inline"><%=f.object.errors[:CSEXO].join(", ")%></span>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>      
<% has_error = f.object.errors.has_key? :CCIUDADRESIDENCIA %>
<div class="control-group<%= " error" if has_error %>">
    <%= f.label :CCIUDADRESIDENCIA, :class=> 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-map-marker"></i></span>
            <%= f.text_field :CCIUDADRESIDENCIA,:class=>'input' %>
        </div>
        <% if has_error  %>         
        <span class="help-inline"><%=f.object.errors[:CCIUDADRESIDENCIA].join(", ")%></span>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally the controller

```
class RegistrationController < ApplicationController
    def index
        date = "20120729"
        id = 1

        #id = params[:event_id] unless params[:event_id].nil?
        #date = params[:event_date] unless params[:event_date].nil?

        @event = Event.find(date,id)
        @groups = Group.all
        @categorias = Category.where("DiaActividad = ? and TorneoId = ?", date, id)


        @registration = Registration.new
        @registration.registrationDetails.build( :person => Person.new)
    end


    def save
        @registration = Registration.new(params[:registration])
        if @registration.save
            redirect_to :controller => 'home'
        else
            date = params[:event_date]
            id = params[:event_id]  
            @event = Event.find(date,id)
            @groups = Group.all
            @categorias = Category.where("DiaActividad = ? and TorneoId = ?", date, id)
            render :action => 'index'
        end
    end

end
```

What is happening? well first of all, the changes on any field are not saved, and the validations are not displayed. When i submit the form, it returns to the same page, and seems the form has errors but no one is displayed, and the data is lost.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don´t Know why but I solved using resources.

In my routes.rb file

```
resources :registrations
```

Before I have something like this.

```
  match 'registration/(:event_date)/(:event_id)' => 'registration#index'
  match 'registration/save' => 'registration#save'
```

I think the problem was my custom routes. But i really don`t know.